# Product search showing in google search for magento development site

Tags: magento-1.7, seo

I am facing an problem in my development site,when I am searching a product in Google the product search are showing result for the development site. This I want to disable it.

anyone has any idea regarding this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a file the root of your magento instance named `robots.txt` with this content.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Answer (score 1):

Use  `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` on your dev site. See [reference](http://www.robotstxt.org/meta.html).
Or you can use .htpassword to prevent your dev site from unauthenticated users. See [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291080/proper-htpasswd-usage).

Comment: and how do you make sure that his doesn't go live?